# CABasicAnimation to emulate a 'pulse' effect animation on a non-circle shape

Tags: swift, animation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am using CBasicAnimation to create a pulsating effect on a button.
The effect pulses out the shape of a UIView, with border only.

While the animation works properly, I am not getting the desired effect using `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")`.

I am using an animation group with 3 animations: borderWidth, transform.scale and opacity.

```
class Pulsing: CALayer {

var animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()

var initialPulseScale:Float = 1
var nextPulseAfter:TimeInterval = 0
var animationDuration:TimeInterval = 1.5
var numberOfPulses:Float = Float.infinity


override init(layer: Any) {
    super.init(layer: layer)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


init (numberOfPulses:Float = Float.infinity, position:CGPoint, pulseFromView:UIView, rounded: CGFloat) {
    super.init()


    self.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor



    self.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    self.opacity = 1
    self.numberOfPulses = numberOfPulses
    self.position = position

    self.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pulseFromView.frame.width, height: pulseFromView.frame.height)
    self.cornerRadius = rounded


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
        self.setupAnimationGroup(view: pulseFromView)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.add(self.animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
        }
    }



}

func borderWidthAnimation() -> CABasicAnimation {
    let widthAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
    widthAnimation.fromValue = 2
    widthAnimation.toValue = 0.5
    widthAnimation.duration = animationDuration

    return widthAnimation
}


func createScaleAnimation (view:UIView) -> CABasicAnimation {
    let scale = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            scale.fromValue = view.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale")
    }

    scale.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1.1)
    scale.duration = 1.0
    scale.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)

    return scale
}

func createOpacityAnimation() -> CABasicAnimation {
    let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    opacityAnimation.duration = animationDuration
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = 1
    opacityAnimation.toValue = 0
    opacityAnimation.fillMode = .removed

    return opacityAnimation
}

func setupAnimationGroup(view:UIView) {
    self.animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    self.animationGroup.duration = animationDuration + nextPulseAfter
    self.animationGroup.repeatCount = numberOfPulses


    self.animationGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)

    self.animationGroup.animations = [createScaleAnimation(view: view), borderWidthAnimation(), createOpacityAnimation()]
}



}



class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var pulsingView: UIView!

let roundd:CGFloat = 20

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pulsingView.layer.cornerRadius = roundd
    let pulse = Pulsing(
        numberOfPulses: .greatestFiniteMagnitude,
        position: CGPoint(x: pulsingView.frame.width/2,
                          y: pulsingView.frame.height/2)
        , pulseFromView: pulsingView, rounded: roundd)

    pulse.zPosition = -10
    self.pulsingView.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, at: 0)
}




}
```

My problem is transform.scale is maintaining the aspect ratio of the UIView it's pulsating from during the animation.

**How can I make the pulse grow so there's uniform spacing on both the height and the width? See screenshot.**

[image: Scaling of button]

Comment: please share your path as well....

Comment: The path is simply a UIView with a fixed width/height and rounded corners. The rounded corners aren't even necessary. A square UIView should produce the same results.

Comment: can you post that code as well ? i need to run it o my end

Comment: @jawadAli - everything is posted now.

Comment: you are scalig pulse which is CALayer ... but not the view ... which is in white color

Comment: It doesn't matter what I scale... CALayer or View. The issue is the spacing around the pulse. Post an answer if you think you have a solution to the spacing issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling the width and height by the same factor is going to result in unequal spacing around the edges. You need to increase the layer's width and height by the same value. This is an addition operation, not multiplication. Now, for this pulsating effect you need to animate the layer's bounds.

If you want the spacing between the edges to be dynamic, then pick a scale factor and apply it to a single dimension. Whether you choose the width or the the height doesn't matter so long as it's only applied to one. Let's say you choose the width to grow by a factor of 1.1. Compute your target width, then compute the delta.

```
let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.1
let targetWidth = view.bounds.size.width * scaleFactor
let delta = targetWidth - view.bounds.size.width
```

Once you have your delta, apply it to the layer's bounds in the x and the y dimension. Take advantage of the `insetBy(dx:)` method to compute the resulting rectangle.

```
let targetBounds = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -delta / 2, dy: -delta / 2)
```

For clarity's sake, I've renamed your `createScaleAnimation(view:)` method to `createExpansionAnimation(view:)`. Tying it all together we have:

```
func createExpansionAnimation(view: UIView) -> CABasicAnimation {

    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.1
        let targetWidth = view.bounds.size.width * scaleFactor
        let delta = targetWidth - view.bounds.size.width

        let targetBounds = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -delta / 2, dy: -delta / 2)

        anim.duration = 1.0
        anim.fromValue = NSValue(cgRect: self.bounds)
        anim.toValue = NSValue(cgRect: targetBounds)
    }

    return anim
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Your explanation made sense, and your solution worked perfect. (Have to wait another 11 hours to reward your bounty). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joe I meant to mention this but there really shouldn't be a need for you to use DispatchQueues. Your code would simplify a lot if you just kept everything on the main thread.

Comment: Looks like I need it. Without it, it crashes: Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds] on this line: let targetWidth = view.bounds.size.width * scaleFactor

Comment: @Joe The reason it's crashing is because of this line: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async`. If you remove that and the other DispatchQueue invocations you should be good to go.